# How can we use D flip flop and a combinational circuit to retain a bit?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, logic-gates, asic, boolean-algebra

I am trying to solve a problem, which involves designing a gate level circuit, and I'm stuck on the last part of the problem. The last part wants me to retain the carry flag generated from the adder until I manually reset it. I am trying to increment a number. Whenever the carry is generated I want to store that carry until I manually clear it. However, during the counting procedure, just after carry is generated, counting starts from the beginning, making carry bit 0 and hence even if I use a flip flop, it will contain the last value of the carry flag and not the logic 1 generated earlier.

Comment: The diagram [here](http://www.siue.edu/~gengel/ece484LabMaterial/lab3.htm) might help you.

Comment: No, In the diagram, the carry bit generated is fed back to the adder itself in the next clock cycle. I am looking to store the carry generated only when it's output is 1. Even if reset's itself to 0 the output of overflow should still be 1 until manually cleared

Comment: So *extrapolate* it for your needs.

Comment: I know i have to use a d-flip flop along with certain combination logic ,couldn't figure out the logic

Comment: If you want it to keep set unless you clear it a D-ff is not the most suited component, a simple set-reset ff will be easier.

Comment: So you're saying that the FF should go high at the clock edge  if the carry is high **or** if it's already high? What kind of combinatorial logic would work there?

Answer (score 1):

Connect your carry flag to "S" input.  Clear by asserting "R".
Output is held at "Q" until cleared.

[image: Set/Reset made out of NOR gates]